# how to insert correct date in sqlserver 2005 by vb2012

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

i am having a trouble to insert correct date in sqlserver2005 by vb2012.
when i execute my query it works fine and everything is save in database, but the date is always wrong . it always save 17-07-1894, the date and month change sometime but always it save this year, also the date and month are not correct.
i am trying to pickup date from a date time picker, query works fine and it takes the correct value from date time picker, but save wrong date in sql why ?
also it do same when i update from a different from.
here is my code

```
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_Invoice (fld_InvoiceDate) values  (" & CDate(dtp_InvoiceDate.Value.Date) & ")", sqlc)
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                'MsgBox("Order Save")
            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Exit Function
            End Try
```

please help in this , is there any problem with sqlserver ? i am using datetime as datatype of sql.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `parameters` instead of string concatenation

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_Invoice (fld_InvoiceDate) values  (@invoiceDate)", sqlc)
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoiceDate", SqlDbTypes.DateTime).Value =dtp_InvoiceDate.Value.Date

            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                'MsgBox("Order Save")
            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Exit Function
            End Try
```

Comment: i allready try that but it wont work, i think this is a problem with sql server2005 ,i install the sqlserver on client side and i got the wrong date there too on client side it show year 1900 .so clearly it is a problem with the sql date, any idea to fix that ?